# Q: penalizing variables deviating from a given ratio

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I want my optimization variables   $\phi_1, \cdots , \phi _n >0$ (positive real) to remain around a known ratio, say $\alpha_1 :\alpha_2 :\cdots :\alpha_n$, where $\alpha_i\in (0, 1)$. To be clear, I want

$\phi _1:\phi _2:\cdots :\phi _n \approx \alpha_1 :\alpha_2 :\cdots :\alpha_n$,

where $\phi_i$ are linear in other optimization (binary) variable $x_k\in\{0,1\} $,  expressed as $\phi_i =\sum_k c_{ik}x_k, (c_{ik}>0) $

Plus, I want to penalize from both ways (no overshoot and no undershoot).
Do you have any suggestions for cost function that would penalize variables deviating from that ratio? If you can write in linear form, that would be great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to minimize $$\sum_i \left|\frac{\phi_i}{\sum_j \phi_j} - \frac{\alpha_i}{\sum_j \alpha_j}\right|.$$
Introduce decision variable $z_i$ to represent the summand, together with constraints
\begin{align}
\frac{\phi_i}{\sum_j \phi_j} - \frac{\alpha_i}{\sum_j \alpha_j} &\le z_i \tag1\label1\\
-\frac{\phi_i}{\sum_j \phi_j} + \frac{\alpha_i}{\sum_j \alpha_j} &\le z_i \tag2\label2\\
\end{align}
Now \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} are still nonlinear, but multiply both sides by the denominator $\sum_j \phi_j$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\phi_i - \frac{\alpha_i \sum_j \phi_j}{\sum_j \alpha_j} &\le z_i \sum_j \phi_j \tag3\label3\\
-\phi_i + \frac{\alpha_i \sum_j \phi_j}{\sum_j \alpha_j} &\le z_i \sum_j \phi_j \tag4\label4\\
\end{align}
Now substitute $\phi_i = \sum_k c_{ik} x_k$, yielding
\begin{align}
\sum_k c_{ik} x_k - \frac{\alpha_i \sum_j \sum_k c_{jk} x_k}{\sum_j \alpha_j} &\le \sum_j \sum_k c_{jk} z_i x_k \tag5\label5\\
-\sum_k c_{ik} x_k + \frac{\alpha_i \sum_j \sum_k c_{jk} x_k}{\sum_j \alpha_j} &\le \sum_j \sum_k c_{jk} z_i x_k \tag6\label6\\
\end{align}
Now introduce decision variable $y_{ik}$ to represent $z_i x_k$, together with big-M constraints
\begin{align}
0 \le y_{ik} &\le M_{ik} x_k \tag7\label7\\
0 \le y_{ik} - z_i &\le M_{ik} (1 - x_k) \tag8\label8\\
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{7} enforces $x_k = 0 \implies y_{ik} = 0$, and constraint \eqref{8} enforces $x_k = 1 \implies y_{ik} = z_i$.

Comment: Thanks for your bright answer!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to minimize the $\vert \phi_i -\alpha_i\vert $.
Introduce variables $z_i$ defined by
$\phi_i -\alpha_i \le z_i$
$\alpha_i -\phi_i \le z_i$
where $z\in R_+^i$

Min $\sum_i z_i $
Or
Min $\sum_i \log z_i $ if you consider minimizing $\prod_i z_i$

Comment: Better to use $\phi_i/\sum_j \phi_j$ instead of $\phi_i$ in the constraints, and because $\phi$ is a linear function of binary variables this can be linearized.

Comment: @RobPratt I never thought this would be possible before writing it out. Thanks a lot, this reduces a lot of pain :)

Comment: @Sutanu Thanks, so I first need to normalize both alpha and phi by their respective sum.

Comment: Thanks Sim, I would leave it to Dr Rob to clarify further because since $\phi$ is a term involving a binary, any aggregate may not be convex and also dividing a decision variable but another term involving decision variable may not be solvable by a solver. Like solvers don't like $\frac {x}{y} \le 1$ but want it to be $x \le y$ if both $x,y$ are decision variables (constants, parameters or non-decision variables outside the solver's scope are ok)

Comment: I verified once again, and it seems like I got into a trouble you just mentioned. @RobPratt could you clarify how I can linearize the fraction with binary variables in more complicated cases as follows? 

For example, 
\begin{gathered}
\bar{\phi}_i := \frac{\phi_i}{\phi_1 + \phi_2+\phi_3}= \frac{c_{i1}x_{i1} + c_{i2} x_{i2}}{(c_{11}x_{11} + c_{12} x_{12}) + (c_{21}x_{21} + c_{22} x_{22}) + (c_{31}x_{31} + c_{32} x_{32})}
\end{gathered}
and we have single-choice constraints writing
\begin{gather}
x_{11} + x_{12} = 1,\quad x_{31} + x_{32} = 1,\quad x_{31} + x_{32} = 1
\end{gather}